# Data consist space on Dropdownbox

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown box that contains data, but when I try to inspect element the problem that appears is, the **data contains spaces**.
I've tried to fix it by changing the value of the property `content` pseudo element `::before` and `::after`, but the data from the dropdown box still contains spaces. Has anyone ever experienced it here? and know the source of the problem where?
please help me, I attach a picture of the results of the inspect element, thank you.

[image]

Comment: i has change the content value become content: none

Comment: I think in your html code, you gave the spaces for the binding variable. Show your 3 lines of code. So we can find the solution.